# Cambiar nombre a columna para que no se repita

Tags: php, sql

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una tabla que mostrar y tengo tres columnas que tienen el mismo nombre (Descripcion) y obviamente me trae el nombre de una Descripcion en las tres columnas. Como puedo hacer para cambiar el nombre de la columna y así asignarle un nombre distinto a cada uno y que no se interpongan. Ya probé en la consulta de SQL usar el 'AS' y cambiarle el nombre pero me lo trae como dato booleano y me da error.

```
<?php 

$query="SELECT TMedicamentos.Presentacion, TMedicamentos.Descripcion, MDrogasTP.Descripcion, TAccionTera.DescAccTera, TLaboratorio.Descripcion, RVadMedPlan.Porc_Dto FROM TMedicamentos
        INNER JOIN MDrogasTP ON TMedicamentos.Cod_Droga = MDrogasTP.CodigoDrogasTP
        INNER JOIN TAccionTera ON MDrogasTP.CodAccTera = TAccionTera.CodAccTera
        INNER JOIN TLaboratorio ON TMedicamentos.Cod_Laboratorio = TLaboratorio.Cod_Laboratorio
        INNER JOIN RVadMedPlan ON TMedicamentos.CodNum = RVadMedPlan.CodNum";

    $consulta=$conexion->query($query);
    while ($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
            echo'
            <tr>
            <td>'.$fila['Descripcion'].'</td>
            <td>'.$fila['Descripcion'].'</td>
            <td>'.$fila['Descripcion'].'</td>
            <td>'.$fila['DescAccTera'].'</td>
            <td>'.$fila['Presentacion'].'</td>
            <td>'.$fila['Porc_Dto'].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pone un alias a las columnas

```
$query='SELECT TMedicamentos.Presentacion, TMedicamentos.Descripcion as "desc_med", MDrogasTP.Descripcion as "desc_drogas", TAccionTera.DescAccTera, TLaboratorio.Descripcion as "lab_desc", RVadMedPlan.Porc_Dto FROM TMedicamentos
        INNER JOIN MDrogasTP ON TMedicamentos.Cod_Droga = MDrogasTP.CodigoDrogasTP
        INNER JOIN TAccionTera ON MDrogasTP.CodAccTera = TAccionTera.CodAccTera
        INNER JOIN TLaboratorio ON TMedicamentos.Cod_Laboratorio = TLaboratorio.Cod_Laboratorio
        INNER JOIN RVadMedPlan ON TMedicamentos.CodNum = RVadMedPlan.CodNum';
```

Te dejo un enlace a una página que lo explica [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_as.asp) por si te sirve de ayuda

Salu2